# Adapt Enumerator / Iteratee to Stream

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, spray

I have a Spray application where I'm using [reactive-mongo](http://reactivemongo.org/) to connect to my Mongo database.

```
val collection: BSONCollection = db("ping")
val cursor: Cursor[Ping] = collection.find(BSONDocument()).cursor[Ping]
val e: Enumerator[Ping] = cursor.enumerate()
```

ReactiveMongo's cursor allows me to get the data by chunks. This cursor can be transformed to a play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator which is in turn connected to a play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee where any code I want is called for each element of the collection. "Ping" is my domain entity.

With Spray it's possible to return a Stream[Ping] that will be marshalled into a JSON response. I'd like to know if it's possible to adapt the Enumerator or the Iteratee to a Stream, so I can return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collect[Stream]` instead of `enumerate` on the [Cursor](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.9/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.Cursor) instance to do that:

```
val collection: BSONCollection = db("ping")
val cursor: Cursor[Ping] = collection.find(BSONDocument()).cursor[Ping]
val stream: Stream[Ping] = cursor.toList.toStream
```

EDIT: Used `cursor.toList.toStream`. This will gather all the documents matched by the query, then produce a stream.

Comment: Close. That returns a Future[Stream[Ping]], but when I try it, it returns only the first element of the collection.

Comment: Edited using `cursor.toList.toStream`.

Comment: Do you know if, assuming a collection of a thousand objects, using toList.toStream will load all of them in memory from Mongo, or if they will be fetched one at a time?

Comment: It will eventually load them in memory from MongoDB. In a non-blocking context such as this one, `Stream[Document]` is problematic: a call to `tail` will block for the next document. This is why Enumerator/Iteratees were created :)